# how many times is a line of code executed when the program is running?

Tags: python

Is there some tool that tells me the time the program dwells on each line/block of code in python?

Thanks.

Karthick

Answer (score 6):

Look at the profiler that is part of the standard Python distribution. The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) include some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of line_profiler and kernprof:

http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/